# Delete selected data from database

Tags: android, android-dialog

```
Activity:

        public void delete(View v){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this account?")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                deleteCheque();
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
            public void deleteCheque(){
                try {
                    db=new databaseone(this);
                    Details dt=new Details();
                    int rows=db.delete1(dt);
                    if ( rows == 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Cheque Deleted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        this.finish();
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not delete cheque!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            }
            }

Database:

public int delete1(Details dt) {    
            sdb=this.getWritableDatabase();
            int rows = sdb.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id=?", new String[] { dt.getId()})
            sdb.close();
            return rows;
        }


Logcat :




    03-11 14:51:50.508: D/dalvikvm(384): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5844 objects / 303200 bytes in 363ms
    03-11 14:52:05.698: D/dalvikvm(412): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 951 objects / 64736 bytes in 78ms
    03-11 14:52:20.648: V/one(412): 4
```

I am new in android ..I want to delete the selected data from database using alert dialog box..its not working fine..can anyone help......................................................................................
................................

Comment: what is the use of cursor which is returning in `delete1` method.

Comment: edited my code...no error occurs ..but can't able to delete from database.

Comment: Have you checked your `dt` values??? is it correct? tell us what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Details.
and this function is not well. try change this.

```
public Cursor delete1(Details dt) { 
        sdb=this.getWritableDatabase();
        int rows = sdb.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id=?", new String[] { dt.getId() }); //Where is id?
        return rows;
    }
```

Comment: i want to delete the current data.

Comment: and Why need Dtails dt object? I don't know your thinking goal.

Comment: If new String[] { id } in id, database just delete data id Colum value is id

Comment: @user3400666 please show me Details definition. And then i can more help you.

Comment: And don't forget to close the database ;)

Comment: in details class public String getId() {
  return id;
 }

Comment: ok...i have done like that ..but error occurs as to change method return type as int..what should i do now.

Comment: @user3400666 please change method return type is int.

Answer (score 0):

You should use id of Detail class which is use as primary key in detail table..

i think id is in Detail class. check id in detail class. After Getting id  you can use

```
public int delete1(Details dt) { 
    sdb=this.getWritableDatabase();
    int rows = sdb.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id=?", new String[] { dt.<id of detail class>});
     sdb.close();
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: what should i return.

Comment: You should return int and pass id of details class which is primary key in table.

Comment: where to close the database..error occurs as application didnot close the cursor or database object.

Comment: Use sdb.close(); before return statement.

Comment: can't able to delete.

Comment: i saw logcat, this error not occur due to this code. Any where you are again closing data base.

Comment: where should i close database?

Comment: posted the logcat again ..now this is the error coming

Comment: Do you know You are passing "  Details dt=new Details(); " when you are passing dt it has no id. So please send valid data and pass valid id in delete1()methode.